# Why is php5isapi.dll missing after installing PHP for Windows?

Tags: php, installation

It's been a while since I've installed PHP for Windows, but every guide I've seen online tells me to set IIS to recognize .PHP files with php5isapi.dll.  However, I can't seem to find php5isapi.dll anywhere after installing PHP 5.3.0 and PHP 5.2.10.

If I recall correctly it should be in C:\InstallDir

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try downloading the binaries (rather than the installer). I found php5isapi.dll in those zips, but the .exe/.msi doesn't seem to install that dll.

Comment: If you download the binary zip file from http://windows.php.net/download/ the php5isapi.dll is in the 5.2.1.4 release, but seems to be missing from the 5.3.3 release.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer, the latest version (yes, of the binaries, as noted by the comment above) does not contain this .dll file.  

Comments below on it being replaced by "FastCGI" seem more correct than "Oh it's cool, just run an out of date version." -- Though seriously, CGI seems like a huge step backwards...

Comment: I guess I could change the question title. It should really be "Where can I find php5isapi.dll? And secondarily, why is it not where the docs say it is?" At the time (2 years ago) I really didn't care about getting FastCGI to work, I just wanted IIS + PHP to work.

Answer (score 10):

[FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) replaced `php5isapi.dll`

Comment: And why - for heaven's sake - doesn't install.txt (or any other doc for that matter) mention that with a single word?
Neither the installation howto nor any other readme for PHP 5.3 says that ISAPI is replaced by CGI. So far Fastcgi was an alternative for ISAPI, or vice versa. Just omitting one doesn't make the other a replacement.

Comment: And here's a link to a great article on getting PHP configured on IIS6.  Follow these steps and it works perfectly.  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/

Comment: I think FastCGI is a step backwards, but here is the link to them saying that it is dead: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48299 It is irritating that they decided to drop support, yet leave pieces parts of it around, hinting that they just forgot to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, in the PHP 5.3.5 (Non Thread Safe, & Thread Safe) ZIPs you will find the "pws-php5isapi.reg" file.  This registry key even mentions the php5isapi.dll file and setting it to the path of your PHP install.  However, the ZIPs do not contain the dll file.  Kind of an odd registry key to leave haging around if FastCGI is the only way to go now.
Here's an article on Microsoft:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd450377(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd450377%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I found `php5isapi.dll` in [**archive**](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.2.9-2-Win32-VC6-x86.zip)

Answer (score 1):

The path is: `C:\PHP\php5isapi.dll`

**EDIT**

[A step-by-step guide](http://www.phplivesupport.com/documentation/viewarticle.php?aid=78&pid=8).

Comment: It looks like the binary versions don't install php5isapi.dll, which was my problem.

Comment: AFAIK, you can download the DLL alone.

Comment: That is the path if it were there, but it is not if you had read the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The readme files in the install don't agree with the web pages they mention. The webpages mentioned have loose ends like this one.  Well, anything but consistency, because us programmers love a challenge to maintain job security.