# "The specified procedure could not be found" IIS 6.0 and PHP5

Tags: php, iis, webserver, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am trying to make PHP5 work over IIS 6.0 on Windows server 2003 and i am following this steps:
http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=4

The thing is, there's no file named "*`php5isapi.dll`*" inside the php folder, so I am using php5isapi.dll instead. Is it correct? Or should I try to download the php5isapi.dll from somewhere.

Well, then, I keep following the steps and when I try to execute my php file, I get this message:

> The specified procedure could not be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

I downloaded php5isapi.dll and tried to make it work with it but i am getting this error:

> The specified module could not be found.

Also, after any change, i restart the *Default Web Site* clicking on stop and play.

## UPDATE 2

Now, after rebooting, when trying to access the PHP file, the browser shows a 500 error:

> The page cannot be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that "`php5isapi.ll`" is no longer available for the last versions of PHP as pointed in here:
[Why is php5isapi.dll missing after installing PHP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235437/why-is-php5isapi-dll-missing-after-installing-php-for-windows)

Therefor, what i did was following this tutorial in order to do it with `FastCGI`
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60

I found it on this comment:
[Why is php5isapi.dll missing after installing PHP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235437/why-is-php5isapi-dll-missing-after-installing-php-for-windows#comment8418804_1431232)

After restarting the server, it finally worked.